# How to apply custom font to multiple TextViews within a fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, typeface

I am trying to change the default font for multiple TextViews in android fragment by a custom font. The code to accomplish this is in onCreateView of thefragment  as shown below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_interest, container, false);
    TextView txt1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView txt2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/HoneyScript-SemiBold.ttf");

    txt1.setTypeface(font);
    txt2.setTypeface(font);

    return v;
```

}

The code works if I change the font for only a single TextView  but attempting to change font for multiple TextViews as in the code above, I am getting NullPointerException error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at layout.InterestFragment.onCreateView(InterestFragment.java:81)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
                                                                                     at com.android.niraj.financialcalculator.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:221)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am newbie to java and android programming. Please help me find a solution in changing all the TextViews in the fragment with custom font. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: make sure the textviews you mentioned are present in your layout.

Comment: share your `fragment_interest.xml`..!!

Comment: make sure you have textview with id textview1 and textview2 in your layout fragment_interest.xml

Comment: make sure TextView txt1 and txt2 and Typeface font have not a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```
textview.setTypeface(GloabalTypeface._globalTypeface(this, "Roboto-Light"));
```

here,I m using "Roboto-Light" this font style

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) to do that. (Why reinvent the wheel when something is already done)

Include the dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
}
```

Add your custom fonts to assets/ all font definitions are relative to this path.

Define your default font using CalligraphyConfig, in your Application class in the #onCreate() method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()
            );
    //....
}
```

Wrap the Activity Context:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

You're good to go!

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call these method by passing parent view as argument.

```
private void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
         }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView ) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font.ttf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
 }
 }
```

To apply the font to view itself not at runtime(best for performance)

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for all the `TextView` in your `View` and change the font for each of them:

```
for( int i = 0; i < mainView.getChildCount(); i++ ){
  if( mainView.getChildAt( i ) instanceof TextView )
    mainView.getChildAt( i ).setTypeface(GloabalTypeface._globalTypeface(this, "Roboto-Light"));
}
```